# embedded application

Tags: embedded, hardware, opencv

In the last two months I've worked as a simple application using a computer vision library(OpenCV).

I wish to run that application directly from the webcam without the need of an OS. I'm curious to know if that my application can be burned into a chip in order to not have the OS to run it.

Ofcorse the process can be expensive, but I'm just curious. Do you have any links about that?

ps: the application is written in C.

Comment: I'm not sure that any webcam can support that.

Comment: true, but i plan to add a pic/chip

Comment: If you're going to add a pic micro-controller you should take a look at links about development with PIC.  With some start-up code to initialize the hardware you should be able to do this.  Of course, this would depend on how the hardware is setup to begin with and if it has support for a PIC.

Comment: And are sure it is all C? OpenCV is C++ afaik?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  It is theoretically possible to port your app to PIC chips.

**But...**

There are C compilers for the PIC chip, however, due to the limitations of a microcontroller, you might find that the compiler, and the microcontroller itself is far too limited for computer vision work, especially if your initial implementation of the app was done on a full-blown PC:

- You'll only have integer math available to you, in most cases, if not all (can't quote me on that, but our devs at work don't have floating point math for their PIC apps and it causes many foul words to emanate from their cubes).  Either that, or you'll need to hook to an external math coprocessor.
- You'll have to figure out how to get the PIC chip to talk USB to the camera.  I know this is possible, but it will require additional hardware, and R&D time.
- If you need strict timing control,
  you might even have to program the
  app in assembler.
- You'd have to port portions of OpenCV to the PIC chip, if it hasn't been already.  My guess is not.
- If your'e not already familiar with microcontroller programming, you'll need some time to get up to speed on the differences between desktop PC programming and microcontroller programming, and you'll have to gain some experience in that.  This may not be an issue for you.

Basically, it would probably be best to re-write the whole program from scratch given a PIC chip constraint.  Good thing is though, you've done a lot of design work already.  It would mainly be hardware/porting work.

**OR...**

You could try using a small embedded x86 single-board PC, perhaps in the [PC/104 form factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC/104), with your OS/app on a CF card.  It's a real bone fide PC, you just add your software.  Good thing is, you probably wouldn't have to re-write your app, unless it had ridiculous memory footprint.  Embedded PC vendors are starting to ship boards based on 1 GHz Intel Atoms, and if you needed more help you could perhaps hook a daughterboard onto the PC-104 bus. You'll work around all of the limitations listed above, as your using an equivalent platform to the PC you developed your app on.  And it has USB ports!  If you do a thorough cost analysis and if your'e cool with a larger form factor, you might find it to be cheaper/quicker to use a system based on a SBC than rolling a solution using PIC chips/microcontrollers.

A quick search of PC-104 on Google would reveal many vendors of SBCs.

**OR...**

And this would be really cheap - just get a off-the-shelf cheap [Netbook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netbook), overwrite the OEM OS, and run the code on there.  Hackish, but cheap, and really easy - your hardware issues would be resolved within a week.

Just some ideas.

Comment: I agree. I would never use a PIC chip to do this.

Comment: I happened to have URLs and datasheets for the heavier (16-bit) dspics lying around. One of them is this: http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en022432 

If you assume a 40MHz=40MIPs clock, the avg base fpu operation would take slightly more than 2us.  So about 500kflops theoretical speed. Of course synchronous memory helps in vision apps.

Comment: @ Marco - True.  I didn't mention the dsPICs.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use something bigger than a PIC, for example a small 32 bit ARM processor.

Comment: embeddedarm.com offers some cheap solutions that are actually pretty awesome. they run a full version of linux, too. boards are about the size of a normal development kit for a microcontroller. and no, i am not an employee of embedded arm, i am a customer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll find this might grow into pretty large project.

It's obviously possible to implement a stand-alone hardware solution to do something like this.  Off the top of my head, [Rabbit](http://rabbit.com/)'s [solutions](http://store.rabbit.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=product.display&Product_ID=439&CFID=7626&CFTOKEN=26606887) might get you to the finish-line faster.  But you might be able to find some home-grown [Beagle Board](http://beagleboard.org/) or [Gumstix](http://gumstix.com/) [projects](http://www.pabr.org/cfcam/doc/cfcam.en.html) as well.

Two Google links I wanted to emphasize:

- Rabbit: "[Camera Interface Application Kit](http://store.rabbit.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=product.display&Product_ID=439&CFID=7626&CFTOKEN=26606887)"
- Gumstix: "[Connecting a CMOS camera to a Gumstix Connex motherboard](http://www.pabr.org/cfcam/doc/cfcam.en.html)"

Answer (score 1):

I would second Nate's recommendation to take a look at Rabbit's core modules.

Also, GHIElectronics has a product called the [Embedded Master](http://www.ghielectronics.com/product/107) that runs .Net MicroFramework and has USB host/device capabilities built-in as well as a rich library that is a subset of the .Net framework.  It runs on an Arm processor and is fairly inexpensive (> $85).  Though not nearly as cheap as a single PIC chip it does come with a lot of glue logic pre-built onto the module.

Answer (score 0):

**CMUCam**

I think you should have a look at the [CMUcam](http://www.cmucam.org/) project, which offers affordable hardware and an image processing library which runs on their hardware.